unable to run the graalvm native image
I have installed the graalvm 17 and jdk 17 for my springboot application and added native image plugins and artifact spring-boot-maven-plugin, the image was created successfully but when I tried to run the native getting below issue.
ram@AHU87268 oub-xml-cleanupp % ./target/oub-xml-cleanup
 
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 
:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.2)
 
2024-12-09T10:52:36.843+05:30  INFO 9533 --- [oub-xml-cleanup] [           main] c.h.o.OubXmlCleanupApplication           : Starting AOT-processed OubXmlCleanupApplication using Java 17.0.12 with PID 9533 (/Users/Downloads/oub-xml-cleanupp/target/oub-xml-cleanup started by in /Users/ramb/Downloads/oub-xml-cleanupp)
2024-12-09T10:52:36.843+05:30  INFO 9533 --- [oub-xml-cleanup] [           main] c.h.o.OubXmlCleanupApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-12-09T10:52:36.865+05:30  INFO 9533 --- [oub-xml-cleanup] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-12-09T10:52:36.866+05:30  INFO 9533 --- [oub-xml-cleanup] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-12-09T10:52:36.866+05:30  INFO 9533 --- [oub-xml-cleanup] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.26]
2024-12-09T10:52:36.876+05:30  INFO 9533 --- [oub-xml-cleanup] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-12-09T10:52:36.876+05:30  INFO 9533 --- [oub-xml-cleanup] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 33 ms
2024-12-09T10:52:36.883+05:30  WARN 9533 --- [oub-xml-cleanup] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'oubXmlCleanupApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'oubXmlService': Error creating bean with name 'oubXmlService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'fileService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'oubXmlRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'produceDataSource': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
2024-12-09T10:52:36.883+05:30  INFO 9533 --- [oub-xml-cleanup] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'oubXmlCleanupApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'oubXmlService': Error creating bean with name 'oubXmlService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'fileService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'oubXmlRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'produceDataSource': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.AutowiredFieldValueResolver.resolveValue(AutowiredFieldValueResolver.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.AutowiredFieldValueResolver.resolveAndSet(AutowiredFieldValueResolver.java:167)
        at com..oubxmlcleanup.OubXmlCleanupApplication__Autowiring.apply(OubXmlCleanupApplication__Autowiring.java:17)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.InstanceSupplier$1.get(InstanceSupplier.java:83)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1237)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
        at com.oubxmlcleanup.OubXmlCleanupApplication.main(OubXmlCleanupApplication.java:19)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'oubXmlService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'fileService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'oubXmlRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'produceDataSource': Instantiation of supplied bean failed

But when I try to run the jar it was running successfully without any errors, what could be issue for this, any redactions that should be need and any plugins have to be added in the pom.xml

Can you provide some code?  Are your dependencies defined with provided or compile scope?
